# RxJS: Use shareReplay to POST HTTP request once, then use ID returned to queue updates

Tags: rxjs

Essentially I need:

```
const saveObservable = new Subject().asObservable();
const create$ = of("ID").pipe(tap(() => console.log("executed")), shareReplay());

const subscription = saveObservable.pipe(
  concatMap(({ files = [], ...attributes }) =>
    create$.pipe(
      tap(id => console.log("queue updates to", id))
    )
  )
).subscribe();

saveObservable.next({})
```

This will make it so my initial save operation: `of("ID")` only executes once. Then, all further executions of this save will use the ID returned and queue up.

What I'm struggling with is that I can't put `create$` inside my `concatMap` because it creates a new instance of the observable and `shareReplay` is effectively useless.

But I basically need it within the `concatMap` so that I can use `attributes`.

How can I do that?

```
saveObservable.pipe(
  concatMap(({ files = [], ...attributes }) => {
    const create$ = fromFetch("https://www.google.com", { attributes }).pipe(tap(() => console.log("executed")), shareReplay());

    return create$.pipe(
      tap(a => console.log(a))
    )
  })
);
```

vs.

```
const create$ = fromFetch("https://www.google.com", { attributes?? }).pipe(tap(() => console.log("executed")), shareReplay());

saveObservable.pipe(
  concatMap(({ files = [], ...attributes }) => {

    return create$.pipe(
      tap(a => console.log(a))
    )
  })
)
```

Comment: is create$ a http call or just to save the id for sharing?

Comment: It's an HTTP call. It's where I need the attributes passed to the subject: `fromFetch(..., attributes)`.

Comment: Create$ shouldn’t be creating new instance though

Comment: It would if you put it in concatMap, which is where I need it to get the `attributes`.

Comment: Can u provide more code for create$? Hard to get the big picture, does it take in parameters?

Comment: Edited! Take a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209973/discussion-between-maletor-and-fan-cheung).

Comment: I think this needs a stackblitz demo of what doesn't work because I'm confused as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best approach, but here's what comes to mind.

You can use a `ReplaySubject` as a **subscriber**. When used this way, it will cache the emitted values that come from the source.

So you could have something like this:

```js
const replSubj = new ReplaySubject(/* ... */);


saveObservable.pipe(
    concatMap(({ files = [], ...attributes }) => {
        // We first subscribe to `replSubj` so we can get the stored values
        // If none of the stored ones match the condition imposed in `first`,
        // simply emit `of({ key: null })`, which means that a request will be made
        return merge(replSubj, of({ key: null }))
            .pipe(
                // Check if we've had a request with such attributes before
                // If yes: just return the stored value received from the subject
                // If not: make a request and store the value
                // By using `first` we also make sure the subject won't have redundant subscribers
                first(v => v.key === attributes.identifier || v.key === null),
                switchMap(
                    v => v.key === null
                        ? fromFetch("https://www.google.com", { attributes }).pipe(tap(() => console.log("executed")))
                            .pipe(
                                map(response => ({ key: attributes.identifer, response })), // Add the key so we can distinguish it later
                                tap(({ response }) => replSubj.next(response)) // Store the value in the subject
                            )
                        : of(v.response) // Emit & complete immediately
                ),
            )
    }),
);
```

Note that `ReplaySubject` can have a second parameter, `windowTime`, which specifies how long the values should be cached.

Comment: Check out my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with:

```
  let create$: Observable<EnvelopeSummary>;

  const [, , done] = useObservable(
    updateObservable$.pipe(
      concatMap(attributes => {
        if (create$) {
          return create$.pipe(
            concatMap(({ envelopeId }) =>
              updateEnvelope({ ...userInfo, envelopeId, attributes }).pipe(
                mapTo(attributes.status)
              )
            )
          )
        } else {
          create$ = createEnvelope({ ...userInfo, attributes }).pipe(
            shareReplay()
          );
          return create$.pipe(mapTo(attributes.status))
        }
      }),
      takeWhile(status => status !== "sent")
    )
  );
```